# Jquery: React to dynamic classes in forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dynamic-class

I have made a HTML form that is split up into sections.

I am using Jquery to add classes to the body element depending on what sections have been filled in.

By default, the body has a class of `purchase-stop`. When all the sections are filled in, this changes to `purchase-go`.

When the user clicks on the submit button, I use the following code to display a message:

```
$("input").on('click', '.purchase-stop', function()
{
    alert("You haven't visited all sections. Please visit them all to ensure you are happy with the choices");
});
```

The trouble is this will display even `purchase-stop` has been changed to `purchase-go`.

How can I get it to only display when the classes is `purchase-stop`?

Also, two fields on the form are mandatory. I use the following code to check if these mandatory sections are filled in:

```
$(".changing-room").submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var isFormValid = true;
        $("input.required").each(function()
        {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()).length === 0)
            {
                $(this).parent().addClass("error");

                isFormValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).parent().removeClass("error");
            }
        });
        if (!isFormValid)
        {
            alert("Some fields are blank (highlighted in red). Please fill them in");
            $('input').blur();
        }

        if (isFormValid)
        {
            $('body').addClass('purchase-active');
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
        return isFormValid;

    });
```

But again, I only want it to run when the body class is set to `purchase-go` (and not `purchase stop`).

According to the Jquery docs, I have to get Jquery to run on a dynamic class (as `purchase-go` is not in the HTML on load). To do this, I have to use [On() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
The on function is made up as follows:

```
.on("action [e.g. click]", "[trigger element]", function(event)
```

However, I have specified a trigger element, but it doesn't work.

Comment: call you click handler only after you change the class of body to purchase-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on()` doesn't work the way you think.

`$("[source].on("[action]", "[trigger element]", function(event)`

When you use `on`, you are binding to the `source` element, and the event is triggered for `action` when it occurs on `trigger element` within `source`.

So in your case, you are setting up a click handler to fire when an element with the class `purchase-stop` **which is a descendant of** any `input` is `click`ed.

You will need to do something like this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    if ($('body').hasClass('purchase-stop')) {
        alert("You haven't visited all sections. Please visit them all to ensure you are happy with the choices");
    }
});
```

Though, using a class name on the body to indicate whether the form is valid is a little odd. You could add that functionality to your validation function.

Comment: That works brilliantly, but how can I get the code to check the mandatory sections to only trigger when purchase-go is attached to the body class. I have tried wrapping it in an If .hasClass statement,  but it doesn't work. The reason I am using body classes, is because the CSS changes with different styles for different devices.

Comment: Are you saying you only want to do the validation in the `$(".changing-room").submit()` block when the body has the right class?

Comment: At the top of that submit handler, you should be able to do this: `if (!$('body').hasClass('purchase-go')) { return; }`

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. I have copied my code into a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/SpReN/

Comment: The check for the class needs to be **inside** the click handler.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/YeBHX/1/  That also doesn't work. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Well, you probably need to `preventDefault` or return something either way. Also, in your fiddle, it looks like you have a few extra issues. In your html, your form is outside the `changing-room` `article`, so `$(".changing-room form")` won't select anything. That's probably your biggest issue.

Comment: Thanks! I changed $(".changing-room form") to $('input[type="submit"]') and it worked!